# insertSubVIew taking a "long" time

Tags: swift, view, uiviewcontroller

In my container controller, the user can pan the views to switch to different views. When the pan gesture begins, it's add the view of the new view controller to the view with: `view.insertSubView(view:, atIndex:)`

After researching a bit, I noticed this step takes about 0.03 sec (while the other things are all 0.001-0.002 sec). This causes the transition to stotter a bit which is kind of annoying.

The view controller is created at the beginning of the app as a global, using the storyboard.

Also, this only happens when the view is loaded for the first time. The transitions are all fluently after.

What can I do to preload the views so it won't take so "long" when its loaded for the first time?

**EDIT:**
SURROUNDING CONTEXT:

```
var pendingViewController: UIViewController! {
    didSet {
        if let pending = pendingViewController {

            addChildViewController(pending)

            let index = view.subviews.count - 1

            NSLog("start insert view test")
            view.insertSubview(pending.view, atIndex: index)
            NSLog("end insert view test")

            pending.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        }
    }
}
```

Because it only happens when the view is loaded for the first time I was thinking the problem could be somewhere with the `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`. The results are shown below. Only `viewDidLoad` took a small amount of time (0.005 seconds). There's a gap of 0.02 sec before getting to `viewDidLoad` though, but I have no idea what it could be.

```
2015-12-17 15:15:57.116 Valor[777:232799] start insertView view test
2015-12-17 15:15:57.136 Valor[777:232799] start viewDidLoad test
2015-12-17 15:15:57.141 Valor[777:232799] end   viewDidLoad test
2015-12-17 15:15:57.142 Valor[777:232799] start viewWillAppear test
2015-12-17 15:15:57.144 Valor[777:232799] end   viewWillAppear test
2015-12-17 15:15:57.146 Valor[777:232799] end   insertView view test
```

Comment: Could you please show the surrounding context (where the insertion occurs)?

Answer (score 2):

Use instruments to find out where slow code is happening, not log statements with timestamps. This will show you (including system calls) *exactly* where the time is being spent.

Inserting subviews can be slow because of layout. However, your trace (such as it is) suggests the time is being spent creating and loading the view of the view controller. You say this view comes from a storyboard. What is in there? How many other things get triggered when this view loads? Use the time profiler and you will be able to tell. It could be something as simple as a property you're giving a default value to that could instead be a lazy value.

> The view controller is created at the beginning of the app as a global, using the storyboard.

If this is the case then you can force loading of the view controller's view by doing something like

```
let hack = viewcontroller.view
```

Accessing the `view` property of the view controller causes it to load up the view from the storyboard.

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful. From the results of time profiler I can see what happens in those 30 ms: 17 ms goes to loading the storyboard elements (table view, search bar and constraints), 8 ms goes to` viewDidLoad` and another 5 ms for inserting view and adding to the child view controller. It doesn't seem like I can change much to lower this 30 ms so I was wondering if there's a way to preload all this somewhere else?

Comment: updated. It's not a solution I'm very proud of but it does work

Comment: Thanks, seems like I can't preload it either unless I change half of my codes. I think I'm going to create the view controller programmatically to reduce loading time. I hope that would solve it.

Comment: Loading from code isn't usually much faster than loading from a storyboard

Comment: You could try adding the view before the gesture happens, just having it ready to appear whenever the user needs it

Comment: If I create the controller programmatically, the table view / searchbar can be loaded at initialization no? Then I don't have to wait for them to load when the view is accessed, or am I completely wrong? That could be an idea, like when VC1 is loaded, I should load VC2 into `pendingViewController` already? The views are dynamically loaded though, so I'll have to preload all of them into a separate `pendingViewController`. Let me try to finish doing it programmatically first :). Thanks for the advices so far!

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, I see one strange thing: the index for inserting `pending.view`. If the view count on your view is 5 for example, that means that the indices of its subviews vary from 0 to 4. And then, you want to put the new subview at index 4 (= 5 - 1) while there's one already on your view which has index = 4. AFAICS, you meant 5 instead of 4. So, you should ether stick to `let index = view.subviews.count` and then insert the new view at that index, or just use `view.addSubview(pending.view)`. I hope this will help you out.

Comment: The index was just an example, and I don't think it would help reducing the loading time if I changed this. Thanks though.

Comment: I see, but please try it. I suppose, inserting a view at an "already taken" index may cause redundant layout and rendering operations. It will not become worse at least, so give it a try :)

Comment: Thanks, I already tried it at the top and everything else too actually ;d Sadly, it didn't help.